# Construct the feature vectors from image patches with different scale or irregular image patches

Tags: image-processing, vector, machine-learning, classification, feature-extraction

I have met a problem of feature extraction (or feature vectors construction). In classification problems (e.g., digit classification), normally we have got images with the same size or very similar scaling factors. For example, we have images of 28x28 pixels like these:

[image]

Then in order to extract features, we can either run some filtering on these images or reshape the image into a feature vector that has the same size 28x28x1 = 784x1.

However, if we had some images with quite different sizes or image scale factors. How can we generate a feature vector to feed the further classification algorithms? For example:

[image]

Then how can we generate uniform sized feature vectors for these digits (i.e., image patches with different scale)?

The digit classification is just a simple example, maybe down-sampling one image or up-sampling the other one can solve the problem. But if these are more complex natural images what should we do?

The other problem maybe more typical, for example, we have got an image over-segmented using some super-pixel algorithms, like this:

[image]

We want to classify each segmented super-pixel (irregular image patch) into wall, sky, roof and etc. Because these image patches are irregular, and how can we generate uniform sized feature vectors from these?

One obvious way seems to do the zero padding. However, I am not quite sure how to do this properly. For example, should we always put the image data at the central of the vector or at the beginning of the vector (see below)?

Should we do something like this
[0 0 0 5 6 2 1 2 4 5 6 0 0 0];
[0 0 0 0 0 2 4 5 6 0 0 0 0 0];

or

[5 6 2 1 2 4 5 6 0 0 0 0 0 0];
[2 4 5 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];

Non-zero values are the actual image pixel data. Will this influence the final classification?

A more complex case is that the irregular super-pixels with different scaling factors, then how can we generate the feature vectors?

Thanks a lot.

A.